# How to fix horizontal scrollbar fixed in extjs grid?

Tags: extjs4, scrollbar

My grid has a lot of vertical data which increases height of the grid.
And to move horizontally i.e to move the horizontal scroll bar I need to first move the vertical scroll bar low below and the move the horizontal bar and then again the vertical bar to see the top records.

Is there a way that the horizontal bar is always visible i.e its fixed.So that I dont need to go further down.

Answer (score 0):

if the only thing in your page is grid, you cantry adding your grid to a viewport.

```
 var _viewport = new Ext.Viewport({
        layout: 'fit',
        items: grid,
        renderTo: Ext.getBody()
    });
```

Regards.